# Can an IntelliJ plugin fold one-line javadoc comments?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-plugin

I am writing an IntelliJ Plugin to help with coding standards and conventions at my company.

We have some requirements concerning where Javadoc should be used, and I'm creating code inspections and quick fixes for helping with that. Unfortunately, it will lead to a lot of `/** {@inheritDoc} */` about the codebase, which I find ugly. I want to create some functionality in the plugin to replace this text visually in the editor with just "Inherits Javadoc". I know the editor has this functionality because it's what IntelliJ does natively with `@SuppressWarning` annotations and `// language=sql` comments, but I'm unsure on how to implement it in a plugin.

I tried a `FoldingBuilder`, but it doesn't seem to do anything when the `FoldingDescriptor` only covers a single line.

```kotlin
import com.intellij.lang.ASTNode
import com.intellij.lang.folding.FoldingBuilder
import com.intellij.lang.folding.FoldingDescriptor
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.Document
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.FoldingGroup
import com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbAware
import com.intellij.psi.javadoc.PsiDocComment
import com.intellij.psi.util.PsiTreeUtil

class InheritDocFoldingBuilder : FoldingBuilder, DumbAware {
    private val text = "{@inheritDoc}"
    private val foldingGroup = FoldingGroup.newGroup("inheritDoc")

    override fun buildFoldRegions(node: ASTNode, document: Document): Array<FoldingDescriptor> {
        val descriptors = mutableListOf<FoldingDescriptor>()

        val docComments = PsiTreeUtil.findChildrenOfType(node.psi, PsiDocComment::class.java)
        for (docComment in docComments) {
            if (docComment.text.contains(text)) {
                descriptors.add(FoldingDescriptor(docComment.node, docComment.textRange, foldingGroup))
            }
        }

        return descriptors.toTypedArray()
    }

    override fun getPlaceholderText(node: ASTNode): String? = if (isInheritDoc(node)) "Inherits Javadoc" else null

    override fun isCollapsedByDefault(node: ASTNode): Boolean = isInheritDoc(node)

    private fun isInheritDoc(node: ASTNode): Boolean {
        return node.psi is PsiDocComment && node.text.contains(text)
    }
}
```

If I change this so that the `FoldingDescriptor`'s range includes either the whitespace before or after the javadoc comment, then it works fine, except it looks weird because it appears on either the line above or below (depending on which whitespace I've included)

I also tried an `InlayHintsProvider` where I custom-implemented the `InlayPresentation` and tried to just draw the hint *over top of* the javadoc comment with a filled rectangle and a string, but it looks like the actual text of the document gets painted after everything else so it can't be covered up like that.

Is there any way what I want can be done?

Thanks.